# Characteristic polynomial index coefficient

Tags: recurrence-relations

My questions stems from the first link of this search, a downloading pdf, problem 13 of the first "Mock AIME": [thomas mildorf aime](https://www.google.com/search?q=thomas%20mildorf%20aime&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS872US873&oq=thomas%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j46j0j69i60l3.983j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

We have a recurrence relation $64=7R_n+2R{n-1}+9R_{n-2}$, and part of the problem involves finding a closed form of the recurrence. We have $7x^3+2x^2-9x=7x^2+2x-9 \Longleftrightarrow 7x^3-5x^2-11x+9=(x-1)^2(7x+9)=0.$ Then the solution states,

> This implies that we have $R_n=a\cdot n + b + c\cdot\left(\frac{-9}{7}\right)^n.$ We solve for $a,b,c$ by checking the first three terms: \begin{align}&R_0=b+c=10\\&R_1=a+b-\frac{9c}{7}=-2\\&R_2=2a+b+\frac{81c}{49}=\frac{158}{7}\end{align}

But why do we have $a\cdot n$ instead of $a$? There is a double root of $1$ in the characteristic polynomial, so why don't we have $R_n=a(1)^n+b(1)^n+c(\frac{-9}{7})^n=a+b-\frac{9}{7}c$ instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homogeneous linear difference equation with multiple roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113188/homogeneous-linear-difference-equation-with-multiple-roots)

Comment: FYI, other related posts here include [Solving for the closed term solution of a third order recurrence relation with real constant coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463754/602049), [Linear recurrence by characteristic equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/994769/602049), [Finding the closed form solution of a third order recurrence relation with constant coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478927/602049), [Solving a recurrence relation with the characteristic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/518088/602049), (cont.)

Comment: ... [How to find unique solutions to recurrence relation $a_n =10a_{n-1}-32a_{n-2}+32a_{n-3}$ with $a_0=5$, $a_1=18$, $a_2=76$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3153975/602049) and [Show a solution to a recurrence relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2158864/602049).